# Background worker component for a WPF window

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker

In Winforms, we have a BackgroundWorker component under 'Components' tab in toolbox. Is there something equivalent to this in WPF application?

Comment: No need for "toolbox" stuff in WPF. It is strongly recommended that you familiarize yourself with XAML, DataBinding and proper MVVM if you're working with WPF. Forget winforms.

Comment: also yes, you can use `BackgroundWorker` in WPF but you have to create it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly recommend learning about [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx), and using [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) from the view model.

Or even better, [use a Task from TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I think its very easy if I just instantiate a background worker from code-behind in the constructor of the XAML window. That solves my problem.